# VBScript to change windows Administrator password

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBScript which can change the windows local administrator password (without asking the previous one) entered by the user...

I found the script which can reset the password but this scripts are not asking to input the password... :(

Please help me on this issue...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have active directory? If so, why not do this via policy?

Comment: publish your script, we'll see what we can do

Comment: Need to see your script but seems we can assume you want to change the password progmatically, which means it should *not* ask for input but should take it from the script. Your question leads to more questions. Can you please add your code and clarification?

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
strComputer = "." ' Local Computer
strUser = "Admin"

SET objUser = GETOBJECT("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser)
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
objUser.SetInfo

strComputer = "." ' Local Computer
strUser = "Administrator"

SET objUser = GETOBJECT("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser)
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: its a vbs script by the way ;) just open a notepad and copy paste you can run it with a sysprep for example